# Prevent Haskell's getArgs from parsing glob expressions

Tags: haskell, console, arguments

I'm using `getArgs` in my Haskell program to parse arguments from the command line. However, I've noticed that I have problems when I call my program like this:

```
runhaskell Main *.hs .
```

As you can imagine, `Main` looks at `*.hs` files in the `.` directory.

But there's a problem. The code below doesn't behave as I'd expect.

```
import System

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    print args
```

I want to see

```
args = ["*.hs","."]
```

but instead I see

```
args = ["file1.hs","file2.hs","file3.hs","."]
```

My program needs to expand the glob expression itself because it does it in multiple directories. But how can I have `getArgs` return the raw list of arguments instead of trying to be magical and do the parsing itself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't haskell, this is your shell.

Normally file globs (like `*.hs`) are interpreted by the shell before the command is passed to haskell.

To see this try running

```
 runhaskell Main '*.hs' .
```

The single quotes will prevent your shell from interpreting the glob, and pass the argument as-is to `runhaskell`.

Comment: You're certain? How can I do `grep -R search *.hs` then?

Comment: @Eliot: You can't. I mean you can, but it doesn't do what you want (i.e. it acts the same way as if the `-R` wasn't there).

Comment: @Elliot, note that if there are no files matching `*.hs` in the current directory, the shell leaves the `*.hs` argument as is, which may be a source of confusion.

Comment: @Rotsor: Some shells (e.g. bash) do. Others (e.g. zsh) give an error message in that case (which is arguably less confusing).

Comment: @Rotsor @sepp2k: And some shells expand *.hs to nothing at all (since it had no matches).

Comment: @Rotsor @rampion: this is configurable in bash (isn't everything?) `shopt -s nullglob` to remove a glob pattern that doesn't match any files.  `shopt -u nullglob` for the default behaviour of leaving an unmatched pattern as-is.

Answer (score 8):

getArgs doesn't parse the glob expressison - getArgs never sees the glob expression. The glob expression is parsed and expanded by your shell before your program even starts.

There's nothing you can do inside your program to prevent this - your only option is to escape the glob in the shell (by adding a backslash before the `*` for example or surrounding the argument with single quotes).